# Elm routing specifying route instead of path

Tags: elm

I am very new to Elm and have just looked at the Elm tutorial app https://github.com/sporto/elm-tutorial-app

I was wondering how I could change page when clicking on a link specifying the Route instead of the path.

This is the routing

```
type Route
    = HomeRoute
    | NotFoundRoute

matchers : Parser (Route -> a) a
matchers =
    oneOf
        [ map HomeRoute top ]

parseLocation : Location -> Route
parseLocation location =
    case (parsePath matchers location) of
        Just route ->
            route

        Nothing ->
            NotFoundRoute
```

Now in the view I would like to pick HomeRoute when clicked on the menu link

```
menuItems : List MenuItem
menuItems =
  [ { text = "Dashboard", iconName = "dashboard", route = HomeRoute }
  ]


viewDrawerMenuItem : Model -> MenuItem -> Html Msg
viewDrawerMenuItem model menuItem =
  Layout.link
    [ Layout.onClick (NavigateTo menuItem.route)
    , (Color.background <| Color.color Color.BlueGrey Color.S600) when (model.route == menuItem.route)
    , Options.css "color" "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.56)"
    , Options.css "font-weight" "500"
    ]
    [ Icon.view menuItem.iconName
        [ Color.text <| Color.color Color.BlueGrey Color.S500
        , Options.css "margin-right" "32px"
        ]
    , text menuItem.text
    ]
```

I would like to implement the Msg NavigateTo but am not sure how.

```
 [ Layout.onClick (NavigateTo menuItem.route)
```

I could create an update NavigateTo that takes a route as string and then have Navigation create a new Url. Like

```
NavigateTo path ->
            (model, Navigation.newUrl path)
```

But instead of using a path as string I'd rather use the union type Route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any case you need a function for converting route to string:

```
pageToString : Route -> String
pageToString route =
    case page of
        HomeRoute -> "home"
        AboutRoute -> "about"
        ContactRoute -> "contact"
        LoginRoute -> "login"
        DashboardRoute -> "dashboard"
        NotFoundRoute -> "404"
```

And then you can do something like:

```
NavigateTo : Route -> (Model, Cmd a)
NavigateTo route ->
            (model, (Navigation.newUrl <| pageToString route))
```

Comment: Thanks a alot. It does make sense and works well like that.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not going to want to go down the `Hop` route as it is [deprecated for Elm v0.18](https://github.com/sporto/hop/issues/45). `Navigation` has [crude example](https://github.com/elm-lang/navigation/blob/2.0.1/examples/Example.elm) of how it should be done currently.

Adding to a different comment, it may be wiser to do a `String.join` on a `List String` since you can build a `Parser` that can handle many slashes.

```
reverse : Route -> String
reverse route =
    String.join "/" 
        << (::) ""
    <| case route of
          Index ->
              [ "" ]

          Foo ->
              [ "foo" ]

          FizzBuzz x ->
              [ "fizz", "buzz", x ]
```

(I'd leave this as a comment, but StackOverflow has that silly reputation limit)